# Problem viewing Active Directory users from external server

Tags: security, active-directory, iis, remote

I'm trying to set up a website on an external web server (IIS 6 on Win 2k3) such that:

- Anonymous access is denied
- Users have to log in with their Active Directory username / password
- I can grant specific permissions to specific users in Windows Explorer

I **think** I have correctly established a VPN connection between the two servers.  In fact the IIS side of it works!  However, in Windows Explorer, when I click on the Security tab, I cannot see the AD domain, so I cannot search for the users I need to grant permissions to.

---

EDIT:  Per mfinni, I am adding more detail:

In IIS 6, I can go to a website > Properties > Directory Security > Authentication and Access Control.  I can then uncheck "Enable anonymous access," check "Basic Authentication," and then for the "Default Domain" I can click on "Select...".  In the popup that appears, I can see the domain!  Moreover, when I choose the domain, my website now requires me to authenticate, and the credentials stored in the remote Active Directory work.

On the other hand, I also need finer control over individual files and folders, as I need to grant filesystem permissions to individual AD users.  In Windows Explorer (Windows 2003), I right click on a folder, choose the "Security" tab, and click "Add...".  This brings up the "Select Users or Groups" dialog.  Under "From this location" I see the name of the local machine.  **This is where the problem is.**  If this were configured correctly, I would be able to click "Locations..." to see a list AD domains.  However, all I see is the name of the local machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the IIS machine isn't in the domain (or in a domain that trusts your internal domain), this won't work. If it's in the domain, then your VPN tunnel isn't set up right.

Edit with new info in question - Windows Explorer will only show you users and groups from domains that it knows about : either its own domain, or trusted domains. Is your IIS machine in this domain or a trusting domain?

Further edit - I think there's something wrong with your connection to the domain. Check the event logs on the IIS server.

Comment: I apologize, but I am new to all of this, so I don't understand what you're telling me to do here.  I *almost* have it working, since IIS can "see" the domain.  It's just Windows Explorer that doesn't.

Comment: You need to better explain what you mean by that. How does IIS see the domain? In what part of the GUI are you talking about?

Comment: @mfinni -- I've added more detail my original question.  Thank you!

Comment: @mfinni -- On the IIS machine, I went to System Properties > Computer Name > Change.  Under "Member of" I chose "Domain" and typed in the AD domain.  I then restarted the machine.  Had I missed any steps?

Comment: Did you do that just now, or had you done it already?

Comment: I had already done this prior to asking the question.

Comment: OK - then there's something wrong with your connection to the domain. Check the event logs on the IIS server.